# How to implement vNext Web API 2 layer architecture in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to design a good web api architecture using Microsoft vNext technologies (Web API 2).

I am using a project structure, similar to this:

```
Solution                                  
+                                         
+-+Web_API_Users (ASP.NET web api project)
|                                         
+-+BusinessContext1 (library project)     
| |                                       
| +--+BusinessService1 (public class)     
| |                                       
| +--+BusinessObject1 (inner class)       
| |                                       
| +--+BusinessObject2 (inner class)       
|                                         
+-+DataContext (library project)          
  |                                       
  +--+DataAccess1 (public class)
```

I was thinking on separating concerns (mainly to assign different teams and thinking about simplifying code length and readability) at the web api layer by creating different projects, like this:

```
Solution                                     
+                                            
+-+Web_API_Users (ASP.NET web api project)   
|                                            
+-+Web_API_Accounts (ASP.NET web api project)
|                                            
+-+Web_API_Clients (ASP.NET web api project) 
|                                            
+-+BusinessContext1 (library project)        
| |                                          
| +--+BusinessService1 (public class)        
| |                                          
| +--+BusinessObject1 (inner class)          
| |                                          
| +--+BusinessObject2 (inner class)          
|                                            
+-+DataContext (library project)             
  |                                          
  +--+DataAccess1 (public class)
```

But now I am having a second thought that this might be a bad idea. Mainly because I think that having several projects with web api references might collide in the routing, but I have no clear idea if this is true.

All samples and documentation is from a simplistic view with a few routes and simple POCO interactions.

I am seeking advice on making a good architectural decision about this. As you can imagine I am planning on growing this big, so I would like to take the best decision from the beginning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly put your Web API controllers in separate sub-assemblies and then register those assemblies by implementing [`IAssembliesResolver`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection). Also see 
http://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/
http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/using-controllers-from-an-external-assembly-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: It is not the controller side I am worried about, but the WebApiConfig.cs file, where all routes are registered. Do all routes need to be in the same file? And now that you talked about different assemblies, is it better to have them separated or just one monoblock, in performance terms?

Comment: I found out also that I was just not understanding the Web API architecture. Your answer got a couple of good lectures. I finally decided to use just one project and implement as many controllers as I need until I have the need to separate and implement separate assemblies.